# Access has_many active record associations at deep of two level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I am currently working on Rails 3 application which deals Account and Users. I am trying to build active record associations on models. For the current implemetation, I have Account, User and Contact Models. But this involves a polymorphic relations, too. I do have one more separate table called as Relation table which stores these has_many relation's id in it.

Account:

has_many :users, :through => :relations, :as => :asset

User:

has_many :contacts, :through => :relations, :as => :asset

Relation:

belongs_to :asset, :owner

For ex: Account1 has 2 Users. And each User has 2 Contacts under them. Below is Relation table:

---

```
Asset       Owner

User1       Account1

User2       Account1

Contact1    User1

Contact2    User1

Contact3    User2

Contact4    User2
```

---

This keep the tracks of every associations. Each model has_many association defined. 
The thing which I am facing a problem to build association is::

I need to build association from Account to Contacts so that I can lists all contacts that are under User1 and User2, also under an account.
I can perform operations like Account = User1.contacts + User2.contacts.
But this wont be apt.

So is there any concepts in Rails 3 to achieve like ( account.contacts ), so through this instead of iterating over each User to get contact list and then sum them up, I can have contact lists directly ?

Any kind of suggestions are welcomed...